# Combining List<List<double>>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two `List<List<double>>` say x and y. I need to create a new `List<List<double>> z` where each element is `Math.sqrt(xElem + yElem)` where xElem and yElem are corresponding elements of x and t respectively. Can I do this using a single statement using LinQ in C# ?

Comment: @Sayse But LINQ to objects is just loops :)

Comment: @Zache - there is a subtle difference that is pretty self explanatory with the word "query"

Comment: @Sayse: I agree with Zache and `LINQ` has some "nice addons" like `PLINQ` which would be much harder to use "via manual loops"...

Comment: I am trying to learn LinQ. If I had known a clear way or how to approach, I wouldnt have asked in first place... Thanks, for your reply

Comment: I don't get your question. from what I read, xElem and yElem should be doubles, but X and Y list are lists of lists of double. what am I missing here?

Comment: I meant XElem and YElem are elements of elements of X and Y. I thought it is implicit since I used sqrt function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deal with multiple sequences in single Linq statement you need to [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) them first. Since you have list of list you'll need to zip each pair of inner lists too (possibly computing result at the same time). Than normal `ToList` to construct new lists back.

```
 first.Zip(second, 
     (f,s)=> f.Zip(s, 
        (x,y)=> Math.Sqrt(x+y)).ToList()).ToList()
```

Note: as Sayse pointed out if sequences have different length this code will produce result only up to length of shorter sequence. If you need to somehow handle sequences of different length you will need to figure out how to deal with part where only one sequence have elements. In such case regular iteration with `for` and indexing both list may be more readable approach.

Comment: Am I right in thinking Zip wouldn't handle lists of different lengths? The operation the OP is using suggests they would be but you never know..

Comment: @Sayse - Zip will only "zip" portions that match, so indeed if sequences don't have the same lenght this code will produce truncated result. From remarks section: "... the method combines elements until it reaches the *end of one of the sequences*...."

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought; its important that the OP realises this too